# Issue playing UIViewPropertyAnimator again

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewpropertyanimator

I am having an issue with `UIViewPropertyAnimator`, setup as follows:

```
let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 6.0, curve: .linear)

animator.addAnimations {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 6.0, delay: 0.0) {
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.0, relativeDuration: 0.1) {
            someView.alpha = 1.0
        }
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.9, relativeDuration: 0.1) {
            someView.alpha = 0.0
        }
    }
}

@objc func didTapButton {
    if animator.isRunning {
        animator.isReversed = !animator.isReversed
    } else {
        print("start")
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

The first time I hit the button the animation plays fine. However the second time I hit it (after the animation completes) nothing happens. The animator has definitely stopped running (checked via the print statement) but it just doesn't respond.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

According to `UIViewPropertyAnimator` documentation:

```
When the animator is stopped, either naturally completing or explicitly, any animation blocks and completion handlers are invalidated
```

In other words, when you call didTapButton second time, your *animator has no animations*.

To fix it, you should `addAnimations` every time user taps the button.

```
@objc func didTapButton {
    if animator.isRunning {
        animator.isReversed = !animator.isReversed
    } else {
        animator.addAnimations {... //insert you animations config ...}
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried adding this, still failing to play the second time

Comment: @Kex Are you sure you've tested it right? You have a 6-seconds animation, and it will not play second time until first animation is finished. To test it properly you have to lower the duration or wait 6 seconds until playing second time